# Chain helpers or filter data in handlerbars js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Let's say I want to print the first 3 items of a list. So I want to the first `splice` the list and then `each` over the elements. What would be the best way to do this using `handlebars.js`?

The most intuitive way of doing that would be something like `{{#each my_list|splice[0,3]}}` or `{{#each splice my_list 0 3 }}` but handlebars doesn't support such operations.

How can I come up with a helper that chains other helpers (knowing that the any helper at any stage might need additional arguments)?

Note: I don't want to move this logic elsewhere. Let's assume that I definitely want this logic in my templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add your own helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('spliced_each', function(a, from, to, block) {
    var s = '';
    for(var i = from; i < to; ++i)
        s += block(a[i]);
    return s;
});
```

and then your template could say:

```
{{#spliced_each my_list "2" "5"}}
    ...
{{/spliced_each}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Zrd42/

Handlebars is intentionally simple, custom helpers is how you add special logic to your templates.

Comment: Yep, I actually just created a `splice` block helper and which wrapped around the normal `each` helper. I don't get why it *has* to be so simple though, chaining functions is a genuinely required in many scenarios.

Comment: @GauravDadhania: They have to draw the line somewhere. Switch to a different template system if you don't like where they've drawn the line, there's certainly no shortage of options.

Comment: Agreed, looking into sometime a little "smarter" now like DustJS. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching a bit on this, and seems like there is not native possibility of calling chained functions in Handlebars. Seems interesting as an extension for the tool, though.

You can create a Handlebars helper function that let you chain functions. 
With this new helper, you can combine any kind of handlebars helper or your own, consuming every result of a function as a parameter for the next one.

Have a look in Handlebars repo issues: 
[Handlebars repo](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/304#issuecomment-15635762)

There is a nice set of Handlebars helpers as well, not suitable for what you want to do here, but may be will help you with some other operations [Handlebars Helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers)